# SQL Query to get count of matching data from two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have two tables:

Travellers_Report

```
Name    Country Place_of_visit  Return_date
A   United States   Los Angeles 2/27/2013
B   United Arab Emirates    DUBAI   2/21/2013
C   Puerto Rico San Juan    2/28/2013
D   United States   Los Angeles 2/27/2013
E   United States   Boston  2/27/2013
F   Malaysia    Kulalampur  3/1/2013
G   United Arab Emirates    DUBAI   2/15/2013
H   Malaysia    Kulalampur  3/15/2013
I   United States   Los Angeles 2/27/2013
```

Company_presence

```
Country City
United States   Los Angeles
United Arab Emirates    DUBAI
United States   Boston
```

I need to compare the 'Travellers_Report' table's 'Place_of_visit' field to 'Company_presence' table's 'City field' and get the count.

Expected output is:

```
Country               Place_of_visit    Count
United States         Los Angeles       3
United Arab Emirates  DUBAI             2
United States         Boston            1
```

As of now, I have two queries below, but I don't know how to combine them to get the expected result.

```
sqlstr = "SELECT * " & _
  "FROM Travellers_report " & _
  "WHERE Travellers_report.Return_Date >= #" & DOI & "# AND    
Travellers_report.Return_Date <=#" & tempd & "#;"
```

and

```
SELECT Travellers_report.Place_of_Visit, count(1) FROM Travellers_report 
GROUP BY Place_of_Visit
```

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: I'm using VB6 and Access2007 as database.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.Country, a.City, COUNT(b.Place_of_visit) totalCount
FROM    Company_Presence a
        LEFT JOIN Travellers_Report b
            ON  a.Country = b.Country AND
                a.City = b.Place_of_visit AND
                b.return_DATE BETWEEN #date1_HERE# AND #date2_HERE#
GROUP   BY a.Country, a.City
```

Comment: Getting error - 'Between operator without AND in query expression'. changed to 
`SELECT a.Country, a.City, COUNT(b.Place_of_visit) as totalCount FROM Company_Presence a LEFT JOIN Travellers_Report b ON a.Country = b.Country AND a.City = b.Place_of_visit AND (b.return_DATE BETWEEN '02/21/2013' AND '02/28/2013') GROUP BY a.Country, a.City `
Now getting another error: JOIN expression not supported

Comment: did you use single quote? in access wrap the date with `#`.

Comment: Changed to #. but getting same error. JOIN expression not supported

Comment: @kirang i can't determin why `LEFT JOIN` is not working. It's document here [Access 2007 JOINs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx). I'll figure it out. I have no access installed on my machine `:D`

Comment: Okay... I'm a newbie and not familiar with SQL queries. Waiting for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

@kiran try this...
    `SELECT c.country,c.city,count(*) from company_presence as c,Travellers_Report as t where t.city=c.city group by c.city;`

Comment: `SELECT c.country,c.city,count(*) from company_presence as c,Travellers_Report as t where t.Place_of_visit=c.city`
This will prompt me for c.country value,c.city value. When i enter it then result i'm getting is:
`country city Expr1002
United Kingdom London 37488
`
suggestions pls

Comment: can you add a screen shot of output in your qstn

Comment: `SELECT sub.company_Presence.Facility, Count(company_Presence.Facility) AS CityCount FROM 
(SELECT  Travellers_report.*, company_Presence.Location, company_Presence.Facility  from Travellers_report,company_Presence  WHERE Travellers_report.Return_Date >= #2/20/2013# AND Travellers_report.Return_Date <=#2/27/2013# and Travellers_report.Place_of_Visit = company_Presence.Facility) AS sub GROUP BY sub.company_Presence.Facility`

Now only Two columns is there 'Facility' & 'CityCount'. How to add one more column in beginning (Country) by altering this query?

Comment: check this and tell me whether it is working or not...
`SELECT sub.company_Presence.Country, sub.company_Presence.Facility, Count(company_Presence.Facility) AS CityCount FROM (SELECT Travellers_report.*, company_Presence.Location, company_Presence.Facility from Travellers_report,company_Presence WHERE Travellers_report.Return_Date >= #2/20/2013# AND Travellers_report.Return_Date <=#2/27/2013# and Travellers_report.Place_of_Visit = company_Presence.Facility) AS sub GROUP BY sub.company_Presence.Facility`

What is Facility in that table?

Comment: No.same question. `SELECT sub.company_Presence.Location, sub.company_Presence.Facility, Count(company_Presence.Facility) AS CityCount FROM (SELECT Travellers_report.*, company_Presence.Location, company_Presence.Facility from Travellers_report,company_Presence WHERE Travellers_report.Return_Date >= #2/20/2013# AND Travellers_report.Return_Date <=#2/27/2013# and Travellers_report.Place_of_Visit = company_Presence.Facility) AS sub GROUP BY sub.company_Presence.Facility` Getting-`"You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Location' as part of aggregate function`

Comment: sorry. changed the column names of Company_presence table to 'Location' and 'Facility' i.e. Country and City

Comment: No. But its okay. How to change the query to get `Travellers_report.Place_of_Visit` not equal to `company_Presence.Facility`? `<>` operator is not giving the expected result